# cant get bricks to show and ball to hit the bat

Tags: java, oop, programming-languages

I am unable to get the following code to work i i understand that there is a problem in the checkCollision method but i am unable to determine what, or whether its correct in the first place.

i appriciate any help

EDIT: ty for the formatting

currently all the program does atm is spawn a ball at a random position and just falls downwards till it disappears at the bottom of the window what i intend for the program to do is once the ball hits the bat controlled by the mouse it bounces back up and hit blocks which will get destroyed

Comment: Consider posting more information about your current program, its behaviors, its desired behaviors that are not working, etc.  This link might help give you suggestions on just what we need: [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).  Note that I didn't give you the negative vote. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your method `checkCollision()` will not be called at all. See the following lines from your actionlistener (discarded some lines....):

```
if (event.getSource()==btnGo){
    if (counter >0) {
        ....
        if (event.getSource()==timer1){
            ....
            checkCollision();
        }
        else
            btnGo.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Maybe one of the blocks is not closed correctly but in the current version the method is only called if `event.getSource()` is at the same time `btnGo` and `timer1` which is obviously not possible.

Second it seems strange that you compare your bat-position inside `checkCollisions()` (`batY >= paper.getHeight()`). I suppose you meant something like `ballY >= batY`.